# Stop link 'bump' on hover

Tags: html, css

How do I prevent my link from 'bumping' up when I hover over it?

http://jsfiddle.net/s9147kqe/

```css
ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

li:hover {
    border-bottom:2px solid black
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Give 
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ff0000;
} instead giving to li

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add `margin-bottom:-2px;` to `li:hover`.

```css
ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

li:hover {
    border-bottom:2px solid black;
    margin-bottom:-2px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```

**A short explanation:**
The border of a element is added inside the element. Now the content moves up with the thickness of the border. The border is like a "visible padding". To move down the element we have to remove the margin with the thickness of the border.

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian! You were fractionally quicker than Darren and it works too so I'm going to opt for you for the answer. Many thanks for taking the time & the explanation.

Answer (score 3):

You could have the illusion of adding a border by actually having a border on the li, but set it to transparent. Change the border color on hover to black.

```css
ul {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 4px;
    margin: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

li {
    border-bottom:2px solid transparent
}

li:hover {
    border-color:black
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>
</ul>
```